# How to mock module level instance

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have this code that need to test

```
import Logger from './logger';

const logger = new Logger();

export function myFunction() {
  // do something
  logger.log('Hello');
}
```

How to test if function `myFunction` has called logger.log? This is what I ve tried but failed

```
jest.mock('./logger');
const mockedLoggerClass = <jest.Mock>Logger;

describe('Test myFunction', () => {
  it('should call logger log', () => {
    const loggerInstance = {
       log: jest.fn()
    }

    mockedLoggerClass.mockReturnValue(() => loggerInstance);
    myFunction()
    expect(loggerInstance.log).toBeCalled; // Nope no call
  });

})
```

here is another try

```
const loggerInstance = {
   log: jest.fn()
}
jest.mock('./logger', () => {
  return function () {
    return loggerInstance;  // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'loggerInstance' before initialization
  }
});

describe('Test myFunction', () => {
  it('should call logger log', () => {
 
    myFunction()
    expect(loggerInstance.log).toBeCalled;
  });

})
```

I know we should not init logger as global scope but this is not my code so I cannot touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loggerInstance` and the `logger` in the production code are not the same references. `logger` variable will be created right after you import `myFunction`, then you have to get this Logger instance instead of trying to mock another instance.

To do it, you can [get a mock instance by jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances):

```
import { myFunction } from './index'; // a mocked logger already created
import Logger from './logger';

jest.mock('./logger'); // mock it

describe('myFunction', () => {
  let logger: jest.Mocked<Logger>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    logger = (Logger as jest.Mock).mock.instances[0]; // get the mocked instance
  });

  it('should call Logger.log function with "Hello"', () => {
    myFunction(); // action

    expect(logger.log).toBeCalledWith('Hello'); // expectation
  })
});
```

You create a dependency (logger) in a high component (`myFunction`), this is an anti dependence injection pattern, which makes your code become hard to test. You can try module pattern, just `export default new Logger()` instead of `export default class Logger...`

Comment: Nice, thank you so much